# Rebase feature branch on master, excluding previous feature branch

Tags: git

I did something bad. My workflow looked like this:

```
git checkout master 
# we're on master
git checkout -b feature/one
# now do work
git commit -a ...
# create a new feature branch
git checkout -b feature/two
# now do work
git commit -a ...
# oh shoot, I based my feature branch on another feature branch, not master!
```

Basically, I did this:

```
master:      a---b------------
feature/one       \-c--d------
feature/two             \-e--f
```

Instead of this:

```
master:      a---b------------
feature/one      |-c--d-------
feature/two      \-e--f-------
```

Now that `feature/two` exists and has useful commits in it, how can I rebase it to exclude commits from `feature/one` and return to what it should have been based on from `master`?

Comment: Could you use interactive rebase to remove the commits that were part of feature/one?

Comment: @Pythonic1 Probably, but is there a better way to handle it which doesn't involve me hand-picking commits? ie in pseudocode: `git filter-out-commits-from feature/one --exclude master`

Answer (score 3):

```
git rebase --onto master sha123~
```

where `sha123` is the first SHA from feature/two

I would recommend creating a duplicate branch of feature/two to try this on to ensure nothing breaks